How to make a Grid3D_Gas_Controls_Emitter react to motion
When rotating the emitter, the particles move with it, instead of remaining behind
and I'm looking for an effect like this
when rotating it.
I tried copying the "Actor Motion" from the Grid3D_Gas_Master_Emitter, placing it in the gas control emitter, and fixing the issues, expecting a something like this but, the particle system didn't show up.
